# Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The operation has timed out

Tags: azure-storage

I have something like the following code

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage;
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;
private void DownloadFile(CloudBlockBlob blobref , string fileName)
{
 blobref.DownloadToFile( fileName, FileMode.Create);
}
```

It works most of the time

Then one day the following error occurs

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException: The operation has timed out. ---> System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out.
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 693
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteSync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Core\Executor\Executor.cs:line 604
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.DownloadToStream(Stream target, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext) in c:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\workspace\release_dotnet_master\Lib\ClassLibraryCommon\Blob\CloudBlob.cs:line 235
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob.CloudBlob.DownloadToFile(String path, FileMode mode, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext)
```

The solution seems to be to re-generate the Storage Key

Is there a way to prevent this happening?

Comment: Could you please share the value of `StorageException.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation`? It looks like a transient server internal errors, which can't be resolved by key regeneration.

Comment: Changing the key does seem to fix it.  I have added more logging to catch the `ExtendedErrorInformation` next time.

Comment: No, it's not possible that changing the key can fix it. This is a transient error, so it just goes away without any actions from you. I'd suggest you to log the `StorageException.RequestInformation.ExtendedErrorInformation` now so you can see the error details once it occurs again.